# I want to print start time, end time and total execution in R, and append a label to it

Tags: r

```
old <- Sys.time()
```

// MY code

```
new <- Sys.time()
```

total time = old-new
the output comes "Time difference of -6.661923 secs"

instead i want "Execution time : 0.35secs"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` as below:

```
old <- Sys.time()
rnorm(500,0,1)
new <- Sys.time()
x <- (new - old)

sprintf("The execution time is %5.2f secs",x)
```

**Output**:

```
[1] "The execution time is  1.08 secs"
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
old <- Sys.time()
#code
new <- Sys.time()
total_time <- paste0("Execution time: ", as.numeric(new-old), "secs")
```